# How to integrate ASP.NET with DOJO framework

Tags: asp.net, dojo

what's the best way to use Dojo Widget with Asp.NET ?
For example: how to bound a grid with a datasource ?
Thanks

Comment: This article may help you: - [Using Ajax.NET with the Dojo Toolkit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/Dojo-AjaxDotNet.aspx)