# What is dojo and how to use it in asp.net? and when should we use it?

Tags: dojo

I am new in dojo, but i have to use it on my asp.net project but don't know more about it. I have read about it on google but its not clear...

- what is the need of dojo?
- how to use it, any link of simple example of it.
- how it is different from ajax ?

Comment: partially a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564473/how-to-integrate-asp-net-with-dojo-framework which addresses integrating Dojo's dijit set of widgets with asp.net, though Dojo has base JS utilities as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a javascript library, you don't *need* it for any specific task, it's alot easier than writing it yourself (especially if you're not JS savvy).

Dojo have their own [Demos Page](http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/)

It handles AJAX requests but it's not AJAX [AJAX Definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Answer (score 0):

It's a javascript library, just like jQuery or MooTools. You use it like any other javascript library. http://dojotoolkit.org/